# Running synergy server background with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, synergy

Is there any way to make synergy (server side) running background with Mac OS X?

I tried "synergy &", but messages as follow keeps popping.

```
NOTE: disconnecting client "screen2"
NOTE: client "lvd-sungmin" has disconnected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experiments, and the following command solves the issue

```
nohup nice synergy &
```